# In Python, how can I make it so the first 2 elements of a list are added together, then the first 4, then the first 6, and so on?

Tags: python

I am making a game where two players take turns adding a number 1 to 10 to the running total. The player who adds to get 100 wins. I stored the inputs of the players in a list, and at the end of the game, I want to display the total after every turn. The list is in the format:

```
allTurns = [player1move1, player2move1, player1move2, player2move2, ...]
```

How can I add only the first 2 elements and display them, then add only the first 4 elements and display them, and then the first 6, and so on?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've already tried using for i in range(0, counter), then runningTotal += list[i] and incrementing counter by 2 for every iteration. However, I got incorrect values while doing that.

Comment: So put a [mre] in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(sum(list[:i+1]))
```

Or

```
sums = []
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        sums.append(sums[-1] + list[i-1] + list[i])
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one worked.

Comment: Awesome. Second one is probably slightly more efficient for large lists but you wont see any difference with small lists.

Comment: also, do you care to mark my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
allTurns = [1,2,3,6,12,23]
out = []

for n in range(len(allTurns)):
    if n % 2 is 1:
        out.append(allTurns[n] + allTurns[n-1])

if len(allTurns) % 2 is 1:
    out.append(allTurns[-1])

print(out)
```

I've coded it so that it could work for any situation, and not just yours.

Comment: But won't that add only elements 1 and 2, then 3 and 4, then 5 and 6? I am trying to add 1 and 2, then 1, 2, 3, and 4, then 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Should it ignore the last item if it has an odd number of items

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
allTurns = [1,2,3,6,12,23,4]
out = []

for n in allTurns:
    if allTurns.index(n) % 2 is 0:
        i = 0
        for a in range(allTurns.index(n)+2):
            try:
                i=i+allTurns[a]
            except IndexError:
                pass
        out.append(i)

print(out)
```

This is probably as simple as it can get.